# Can't seem to find a proper way of splitting a huge (really huge) video into 1 hour chunks without any loss in quality

Tags: python, windows, video, ffmpeg

I have backed up a video from Milestone system in mkv format. It's a ~106 hours-video with 37 GB size. I have searched for way to split into one-hour chunks without any quality loss. However, I am facing two problems:

1. A python code with `subprocess` has produced videos in arbitrary lengths such as 11 minutes, 1.5 hours, 55 minutes, etc.
2. The produced videos look corrupt. When played I can't use forward or backward (5s) functions, it instantly leaps to the end of the video. There is no such an issue when original video is played.
   Here is the code I used to do the job:

```
import subprocess
import math

input_file = "video.mkv"
output_prefix = "output"
segment_duration = 60 * 60

ffprobe_command = [
    "ffprobe",
    "-v",
    "error",
    "-show_entries",
    "format=duration",
    "-of",
    "default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1",
    input_file,
]
total_duration = float(subprocess.check_output(ffprobe_command))

num_segments = int(total_duration / segment_duration)

for i in range(num_segments):
    start_time = i * segment_duration
    output_file = f"{output_prefix}_{i + 1}.mkv"

    ffmpeg_command = [
        "ffmpeg",
        "-ss",
        str(start_time),
        "-i",
        input_file,
        "-t",
        str(segment_duration),
        "-c:v",
        "copy",
        "-c:a",
        "copy",
        output_file,
    ]

    subprocess.run(ffmpeg_command)
```

I also tested with ffmpeg command with similar output lengths or some other failures such as `Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:0`.

Could someone suggest a better way to do the splitting in any language?
I don't mind spending too much time to split the video, all I need is one-hour videos without any corruption or quality loss.
I am on a Windows machine if it helps.

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/36946/

Comment: @Gyan, appreciate it, but it's not splitting the video into equal parts, I used `ffmpeg -i "video_long.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -c copy -f segment -segment_time 01:00:00 -reset_timestamps 1 video_%04d.mkv` with a trailing `?` after `0:a`.

Comment: a) segments will be split at nearest keyframe so each segment can vary in length.

Comment: yes, I got that, thank you. I believe I am OK with my videos being of different length. But how about my issue 2? Is there any way to handle it?